# TFPDF / UTF-8 in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, utf-8

I'm trying to create a PDF form . Everything is perfect , except that i can not write Greek characters.
For example i want to write:

> "Κανόνες"

and the result is:

> ”Î¹ÎµÏ•Î¸Ï…Î½ÏƒÎ·

I use the TFPDF file than the FPDF because it was supposed to have UTF-8 encoding.

Also i added

```
        $pdf->AddFont($fontName, ' ', 'HelveticaNeue LightCond.ttf' ,true);
        $pdf->AddFont($fontName, 'B', 'HelveticaNeue MediumCond.ttf',true);
```

But i had any result

Any ideas ?

Comment: Where is your font path with .ttf?

Comment: i did it like this : define('FPDF_FONTPATH',"../fonts/");
require('tfpdf.php')

Comment: Please include the .txt file so i can help you out

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code and explore what other font are in the font directory

```
<?php

define("_SYSTEM_TTFONTS", "../fonts");

require('tfpdf.php');

$pdf = new tFPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

// Add a Unicode font (uses UTF-8)
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true);
$pdf->SetFont('DejaVu','',14);

// Load a UTF-8 string from a file and print it
$txt = 'HelloWorld.txt';
$pdf->Write(8,$txt);

// Select a standard font (uses windows-1252)
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);
$pdf->Ln(10);
$pdf->Write(5,'The file size of this PDF is only 13 KB.');

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

The result will be something like this : http://fpdf.org/en/script/ex92.pdf

You have to convert the string you will print to ISO-8859-7 encoding. This is done with
`$text = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-7', $text);`

Refer for the guide for Greek :
http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto7.htm

Comment: Yes , i checked it before , it works perfectly.. But only if i add a .txt file . I want to write Greek in cells without creating other files.

Comment: @PaulKoun, do you have the example of the .txt file? Maybe i can help you out